# Can I force os.walk to visit directories in alphabetical order?

Tags: python-3.x, os.walk

I would like to know if it's possible to force `os.walk` in python3 to visit directories in alphabetical order. For example, here is a directory and some code that will walk this directory:

```
ryan:~/bktest$ ls -1 sample
CD01
CD02
CD03
CD04
CD05

--------

def main_work_subdirs(gl):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(gl['pwd']):
        if root == gl['pwd']:
            for d2i in dirs:
                print(d2i)
```

When the python code hits the directory above, here is the output:

```
ryan:~/bktest$ ~/test.py sample
CD03
CD01
CD05
CD02
CD04
```

I would like to force walk to visit these dirs in alphabetical order, `01, 02 ... 05`.  In the [python3 doc for `os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/os.html#os.walk), it says:

> When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place
> (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse
> into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be
> used to prune the search, **impose a specific order of visiting**

Does that mean that I can impose an alphabetical visiting order on `os.walk`? If so, how?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes. You sort dirs in the loop.

```
def main_work_subdirs(gl):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(gl['pwd']):
        dirs.sort()
        if root == gl['pwd']:
            for d2i in dirs:
                print(d2i)
```

Comment: so, that's pretty awesome. i thought the only thing you could do with generators was iterate over them.

Comment: @ryan_m: That *is* all you can do. But since the next step in the iteration isn't generated until after you are done with the first one, it allows tricks like this. :-)

Comment: Just do be clear, `dirs` is a list, not a generator.

Comment: A subtle point I think is worth mentioning:  it relies on the `dirs` object returned being modified in place, because `os.walk` continues to work with that list.  Hence, if you pass `topdown=False`, so that the dirs are yielded *after* their contents, then it will not work properly.  Similarly, if you did `dirs = sorted(dirs)` instead of `dirs.sort()`, it would also not work properly.

Comment: good point @wim
More on difference between sorted(bx) and x.sort():
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort

Answer (score 7):

I know this has already been answered but I wanted to add one little detail and adding more than a single line of code in the comments is wonky.

In addition to wanting the directories sorted I also wanted the files sorted so that my iteration through "gl" was consistent and predictable. To do this one more sort was required:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(gl['pwd']):
  dirs.sort()
  for filename in sorted(files):
    print(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

And, with benefit of learning more about Python, a different (better) way:

```
from pathlib import Path
# Directories, per original question.
[print(p) for p in sorted(Path(gl['pwd']).glob('**/*')) if p.is_dir()]
# Files, like I usually need.
[print(p) for p in sorted(Path(gl['pwd']).glob('**/*')) if p.is_file()]
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not specific to this question and the problem is a little different but the solution can be used in either case.
Consider having these files (`"one1.txt"`, `"one2.txt"`, `"one10.txt"`) and the content of all of them is a String `"default"`:

I want to loop through a directory that contains these files and find a specific String in every file and replace it with the name of the file.
If you use any other methods which have already mentioned here and in other questions (like `dirs.sort()` and `sorted(files)` and `sorted(dirs)`, the result will be something like this:

```
"one1.txt"--> "one10"
"one2.txt"--> "one1"
"one10.txt" --> "one2"
```

But we want it to be:

```
"one1.txt"--> "one1"
"one2.txt"--> "one2"
"one10.txt" --> "one10"
```

I found this method which changes file content alphabetically:

```
import re, os, fnmatch

def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

def natural_keys(text):
    '''
    alist.sort(key=natural_keys) sorts in human order
    http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/human_sorting.html
    (See Toothy's implementation in the comments)
    '''
    return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split('(\d+)', text) ]

def findReplace(directory, find, replace, filePattern):
    count = 0
    for path, dirs, files in sorted(os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory))):
        dirs.sort()
        for filename in sorted(fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern), key=natural_keys):
            count = count +1
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(filepath) as f:
                s = f.read()
            s = s.replace(find, replace+str(count)+".png")
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                f.write(s)
```

Then run this line:

```
findReplace(os.getcwd(), "default", "one", "*.xml")
```