# Do I understand os.walk right?

Tags: python, file

The loop for root, dir, file in `os.walk(startdir)` works through these steps?

```
for root in os.walk(startdir) 
    for dir in root 
        for files in dir
```

1. get root of start dir : C:\dir1\dir2\startdir
2. get folders in C:\dir1\dir2\startdir and return list of folders "dirlist"
3. get files in the first dirlist item and return the list of files "filelist" as the first item of a list of filelists.
4. move to the second item in dirlist and return the list of files in this folder "filelist2" as the second item of a list of filelists. etc.
5. move to the next root in the folder tree and start from 2. etc.

Right? Or does it just get all roots first, then all dirs second, and all files third?

Comment: I like to use this generator to loop though all the files: `get_files = lambda path: (os.path.join(root, file) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path) for file in files)`.  Then you can use `for file in get_files(path): ...`

Answer (score 139, accepted):

`os.walk` returns a generator, that creates a tuple of values (current_path, directories in current_path, files in current_path).

Every time the generator is called it will follow each directory recursively until no further sub-directories are available from the initial directory that walk was called upon.

As such,

```
os.walk('C:\dir1\dir2\startdir').next()[0] # returns 'C:\dir1\dir2\startdir'
os.walk('C:\dir1\dir2\startdir').next()[1] # returns all the dirs in 'C:\dir1\dir2\startdir'
os.walk('C:\dir1\dir2\startdir').next()[2] # returns all the files in 'C:\dir1\dir2\startdir'
```

So

```
import os.path
....
for path, directories, files in os.walk('C:\dir1\dir2\startdir'):
     if file in files:
          print('found %s' % os.path.join(path, file))
```

or this

```
def search_file(directory = None, file = None):
    assert os.path.isdir(directory)
    for cur_path, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        if file in files:
            return os.path.join(directory, cur_path, file)
    return None
```

or if you want to look for file you can do this:

```
import os
def search_file(directory = None, file = None):
    assert os.path.isdir(directory)
    current_path, directories, files = os.walk(directory).next()
    if file in files:
        return os.path.join(directory, file)
    elif directories == '':
        return None
    else:
        for new_directory in directories:
            result = search_file(directory = os.path.join(directory, new_directory), file = file)
            if result:
                return result
        return None
```

Comment: i like the os.path solution, so os.path will always correspond to the directory that os.walk is in during that iteration?

Comment: btw all the above answers are worth an answer tag, but i can only tag one of the posts as answer! to bad, or is there a way to tag multiple posts as answer?

Comment: oh and another thing, why are you importing os and os.path? isnt os.path included when importing os?

Comment: the os module is a beast 23k lines, but yeah `import os.path` is not required though I remember I had an issue once, but can't remember what it was, any way os.path is the safest way of dealing with paths `os.path.join` it will automaically generate the appropriate `join` in any OS, in windows it knows that they should '\' and escaped in *nix it knows that they should be `/` and it knows when to combine directories or just files, its quite smart :)

Comment: Python 3 note:  next(os.walk('C:\dir1\dir2\startdir'))[0]

Answer (score 89):

**Minimal runnable example**

This is how I like to learn stuff:

```
mkdir root
cd root
mkdir \
  d0 \
  d1 \
  d0/d0_d1
touch \
  f0 \
  d0/d0_f0 \
  d0/d0_f1 \
  d0/d0_d1/d0_d1_f0
tree
```

Output:

```
.
├── d0
│   ├── d0_d1
│   │   └── d0_d1_f0
│   ├── d0_f0
│   └── d0_f1
├── d1
└── f0
```

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
for path, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('root'):
    print('{} {} {}'.format(repr(path), repr(dirnames), repr(filenames)))
```

Output:

```
'root' ['d0', 'd1'] ['f0']
'root/d0' ['d0_d1'] ['d0_f0', 'd0_f1']
'root/d0/d0_d1' [] ['d0_d1_f0']
'root/d1' [] []
```

This makes everything clear:

- `path` is the root directory of each step
- `dirnames` is a list of directory basenames in each `path`
- `filenames` is a list of file basenames in each `path`

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5.2.

**Modifying `dirnames` changes the tree recursion**

This is basically the only other thing you have to keep in mind.

E.g., if you do the following operations on `dirnames`, it affects the traversal:

- [sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670029/can-i-force-python3s-os-walk-to-visit-directories-in-alphabetical-order-how)
- [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859840/excluding-directories-in-os-walk)

**Walk file or directory**

If the input to traverse is either a file or directory, you can handle it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys

def walk_file_or_dir(root):
    if os.path.isfile(root):
        dirname, basename = os.path.split(root)
        yield dirname, [], [basename]
    else:
        for path, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
            yield path, dirnames, filenames

for path, dirnames, filenames in walk_file_or_dir(sys.argv[1]):
    print(path, dirnames, filenames)
```

Comment: Very, very helpful comment. You turned my 20+ lines function to get the first file to 2 lines. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the good visulaization! A picture counts more than 1000 words!!

Answer (score 14):

In simple words os.walk() will generate tuple of path,folders,files present in given path and will keep on traversing the subfolders.

```
import os.path
path=input(" enter the path\n")
for path,subdir,files in os.walk(path):
   for name in subdir:
       print os.path.join(path,name) # will print path of directories
   for name in files:    
       print os.path.join(path,name) # will print path of files
```

this will generate paths of all sub directories,files and files in sub directories

Answer (score 7):

Here's a short example of how [os.walk()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk) works along with some explanation using a few [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) functions.

First note that [os.walk()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk) returns *three* items, the root directory, a list of directories (`dirs`) immediately below the current root and a list of files found in those directories. The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk) will give you more information.

`dirs` will contain a list of directories just below root, and files will contain a list of all the files found in those directories. In the next iteration, each directory of those in the  previous `dirs` list will take on the role of `root` in turn and the search will continue from there, going down a level only after the current level has been searched.

A code example: This will search for, count and print the names of `.jpg`  and `.gif` files below the specified search directory (your root). It also makes use of the [os.path.splitext()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.splitext) function to separate the base of the file from its extension and the [os.path.join()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.join#os.path.join) function to give you the full name including path of the image files found.

```
import os

searchdir = r'C:\your_root_dir'  # your search starts in this directory (your root) 

count = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchdir):
    for name in files:
        (base, ext) = os.path.splitext(name) # split base and extension
        if ext in ('.jpg', '.gif'):          # check the extension
            count += 1
            full_name = os.path.join(root, name) # create full path
            print(full_name)

print('\ntotal number of .jpg and .gif files found: %d' % count)
```

Comment: Just in case anyone else stumbles across this after doing a search for os.walk and "breadth-first" - the above information is incorrect.  os.walk (at least in python 2.6 and 2.7) does a depth-first traversal, NOT a breadth-first traversal.

The exact order in which items are yielded depends on the topdown parameter - if topdown is True (default), then it does a pre-order depth-first traversal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sorted_binary_tree_preorder.svg), while if it's False, it does a post-order depth-first traversal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sorted_binary_tree_postorder.svg).

Answer (score 7):

My answer is very basic and plain. I am a beginner myself and found out my answers searching the web (see esp. [the good documentation at docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)) and trying some test code, such as this one:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startdir)
    print ("__________________")
    print (root)
    for file in files:
        print ("---",file)
```

This prints out the directory tree, where each dir—the starting dir and the included subdirs—is preceded by a line and followed by the files contained in it.

I think you have to keep in mind two things:

(1) os.walk generates a 3-tuple (a triple) <root,dirs,filenames> where

- root is a **string** containing the name of the root dir;
- dirs is a **list** of strings: the directory names directly contained in root, that is, at the first level, without the subdirs possibly included in
  them;
- filenames is a **list** of strings: the filenames directly contained in root.

(2) a for loop such as

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(YourStartDir)
```

loops through root dir and all of its subdirs. It doesn't take a step for each file; it just scans the directory tree and at each step (for each dir in the tree) it fills up the list of the file names contained in it and the list of subdirs directly contained in it. If you have *n* dirs (including root and its subdirs), the for loop loops *n* times, i.e. **it takes *n* steps.** You can write a short bit of test code to check this, e.g. using a counter.
At each step, it generates a 3-tuple: a string plus two (possibly empty) lists of strings.
In this example the elements of the 3-tuple are called: "root", "subdirs", "files", but these names are up to you; if your code is

```
for a, b, c in os.walk(startdir)
```

the elements of the 3-tuple will be called "a", "b", "c".

Let's go back to the test code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startdir)
    print ("__________________")
    print (root)
    for file in files:
        print ("---",file)
```

**First loop**: root is the dir you have given in input (the starting path, the starting dir: a string), dirs is the list of the included subdirectories names (but not of the names of the dirs included in them), files is the list of the included files. In the test code we are not using the list "dirs".

**Second loop**: root is now the first subdir, dirs is a list of the subdirs included *in it*, files is a list of the files included in it.

**...** and so on, until you reach the last subdir in the tree.

There are three optional arguments to os.walk: you can find lots of info about them and their use on the web, but I think that your question is about the basics of os.walk.

Answer (score 5):

os.walk works a little differently than above. Basically, it returns tuples of (path, directories, files). To see this, try the following:

```
import pprint
import os
pp=pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
for dir_tuple in os.walk("/root"):
    pp.pprint(dir_tuple)
```

...you'll see that each iteration of the loop will print a directory name, a list the names of any directories immediately within that directory, and another list of all files within that directory. os.walk will then enter each directory in the list of subdirectories and do the same thing, until all subdirectories of the original root have been traversed. It may help to learn a little about recursion to understand how this works.

Answer (score 0):

I find it is more clear when explaining as below:

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(fold, topdown=False):
    assert set(os.listdir(path)) == set(subdirs + files)
```

there is no error in code above

os.walk() will browse through all folders containing both folders and files or only files; their folders are a list in `subdirs` variable; their files are a list in `files` variable; their address is a string in `path` variable