# Excluding directories in os.walk

Tags: python

I'm writing a script that descends into a directory tree (using os.walk()) and then visits each file matching a certain file extension. However, since some of the directory trees that my tool will be used on also contain sub directories that in turn contain a **LOT** of useless (for the purpose of this script) stuff, I figured I'd add an option for the user to specify a list of directories to exclude from the traversal.

This is easy enough with os.walk(). After all, it's up to me to decide whether I actually want to visit the respective files / dirs yielded by os.walk() or just skip them. The problem is that if I have, for example, a directory tree like this:

```
root--
     |
     --- dirA
     |
     --- dirB
     |
     --- uselessStuff --
                       |
                       --- moreJunk
                       |
                       --- yetMoreJunk
```

and I want to exclude **uselessStuff** and all its children, os.walk() will still descend into all the (potentially thousands of) sub directories of **uselessStuff**, which, needless to say, slows things down a lot. In an ideal world, I could tell os.walk() to not even bother yielding any more children of **uselessStuff**, but to my knowledge there is no way of doing that (is there?).

Does anyone have an idea? Maybe there's a third-party library that provides something like that?

Answer (score 344, accepted):

Modifying `dirs` *in-place* will prune the (subsequent) files and directories visited by `os.walk`:

```
# exclude = set(['New folder', 'Windows', 'Desktop'])
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=True):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
```

---

From help(os.walk):

> When topdown is true, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place
> (e.g., via del or slice assignment), and walk will only recurse into
> the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be used to
> prune the search...

Comment: Thanks, man, you're awesome! (And I guess I need to get in the habit of reading the module docs more in depth rather than just skim over them in a hurry!)

Comment: @ben: `dirs[:] = value` modifies `dirs` *in-place*. It changes the contents of the list `dirs` without changing the container. As `help(os.walk)` mentions, this is needed if you wish to affect the way `os.walk` traverses the subdirectories. (`dirs = value` merely reassigns (or "binds") the variable `dirs` to a new list, without modifying the original `dirs`.)

Comment: You can also use `filter()`: `dirs[:] = list(filter(lambda x: not x in exclude, dirs))`

Comment: Is there any way to do this globally to `os.walk`? Lets say to exclude all */.git directories in all `os.walk` calls?

Comment: @p014k: You could write your own generator function which calls `os.walk` and yields `root, dirs, files` after excluding `.git` (or whatever else you wish) from `dirs`.

Comment: When I try the follow, I get a `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`:

   `def mywalk(walk_path):
        exclude = set(['.git'])
        for dirs, sub, files in os.walk(walk_path, topdown=True):
            dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
            yield (dirs, sub, files)`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: In `for dirs, sub, files in os.walk(walk_path)`, `dirs` is what I called `root` above, and `sub` is what I called `dirs`. Thus your `dirs` is a string, and `sub` is a list of directories. `dirs[:] = ...` raises an error because the string `dirs` does not support item assignment. You basically have the right idea, but I suggest you stick with `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(...)`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) for the meaning of the 3-tuple `(root, dirs, files)` yielded by `os.walk`.

Comment: Wish I could give more than one +1: one for the answer and two for learning about the `list[:]` re-assignment.

Comment: @unutbu Just letting you know that in one case, this optimization has reduced traversal time from more than 100 seconds to about 2 seconds. That's what I call a worthwhile optimization. :D

Comment: Is this by design? This feels sooo hacky.

Comment: why set() and not the tuple in exclude? Because it is unchangeable?

Comment: @Moberg: Yes, it's by design, [explicitly documented for `os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk): "When *topdown* is `True`, the caller can modify the *dirnames* list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in *dirnames*; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes `walk()` again."

Comment: @Timo: `set`s have (average case) `O(1)` lookup time (so no matter how many elements are in the `set`, the cost to check it remains roughly the same short amount of time). If you used a `tuple`, it would have `O(n)` lookup time (so if you doubled the number of things to exclude, you'd double the cost per check).

Answer (score 12):

... an alternative form of @unutbu's excellent answer that reads a little more directly, given that the intent is to *exclude* directories, at the cost of O(n**2) vs O(n) time.

(Making a copy of the dirs list with `list(dirs)` is required for correct execution)

```
# exclude = set([...])
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=True):
    [dirs.remove(d) for d in list(dirs) if d in exclude]
```

Comment: If you want to be more direct at the cost of some memory, you'd better write `dirs[:] = set(dirs) - exclude`. At least it's still \$O(n)\$ and you don't build a comprehension only for its side effects...

Comment: This is not really bad but not idiomatic Python either in my opinion.

Comment: `for d in list(dirs)` is a bit odd. `dirs` is already a list. And what you have isn't really a list comprehension. `dirs.remove(d)` doesn't return anything, so you end up with a list full of `None`s. I agree with @Torsten.

Comment: @ seanahern - I think `list(dirs)` is needed to make a copy of `dirs` so that you are iterating over a copy of the list. If you modify the same copy that is being iterated over, you will get bugs. You end up with a list of Nones but this is fine since `dirs` is modified inplace. The list comprehension is basically just a way to fit the for loop in one line.

Comment: Which solution is O(n**2) and which solution is O(n)?

Comment: @Étienne This one is O(n^2) - dirs.remove() adds the extra multiplier, because it's linear itself.