# Find but do not descend into directories containing the searched files

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have several projects configured by a pom.xml or similar.

I would like to use the linux file command to locate these projects e.g. by `find -name pom.xml`.
This however takes some time because of the deep paths. I would like to use `find -prune` to stop searching in subdirectories when I already find the file, but prune only stops on matched directories not on matched files.

Is there a way to get find to stop descending when the directory aleady contains a searched file?

For clarification; this is what I do without find:

```
pfind() {
    parent=$1 && shift

    for file in "$@" ; do
        path=$parent/$file
        if [ -e "$path" ] ; then
            echo "$path"
            exit 0
        fi
    done

    for dir in $(echo $parent/*) ; do
       if [ -d "$dir" ] ; then
           pfind "$dir" "$@"
       fi
    done
}
```

But I'd rather use a simple way with find so it is better understandable/extendable for others

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name pom.xml -print -quit
```

If you want to speed up the search, you can also work with `locate`, which queries a database instead of scanning the file system.

You can update the database using by running `updatedb`

Comment: this stops on the first matching file but I want to find all files.
I thought about locate too, but then I'd have to ensure that it is updated (which may kill the performance) and also filter the results

Answer (score 0):

One line python:

```
python -c 'import os; print "\n".join(p for p, d, f in os.walk(os.sys.argv[1], topdown=True) if os.sys.argv[2] in f and list(d.remove(i) for i in list(d)))' $PWD pom.xml
```

os.walk idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37267686/1888983