# find command: conditionally prune subdirectories of any directory containing a matched file

Tags: unix, find, pattern-matching, conditional-statements, subdirectory

I'd like to search a directory tree for regular files matching particular patterns, e.g.

```
find -regex '.*\.\(expect\|missing\|ok\)'
```

This is fine, but in my application it is very inefficient -- since if a directory contains at least one matching file, then none of its (many, deep, file-laden) subdirectories need to be searched, since they definitely won't contain any matches.

So how do I `-prune` subdirectories, *only if* a matched file is found in their parent directory?

E.g. if I have the following tree:

```
./a/file.ok
./a/a1/
./a/a2/
./b/file.missing
./b/file.expect
./b/b1/
./b/b2/
./c/c1/
./c/c1/c11/
./c/c1/c11/foo.expect
./c/c1/c11/foo.txt
```

Then I would like to print only:

```
./a/file.ok
./b/file.missing
./b/file.expect
./c/c1/c11/foo.expect
```

without actually searching/traversing all the subdirectory trees of `a/` and `b/`

(This [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107496/find-but-do-not-descend-into-directories-containing-the-searched-files) approaches what I want, but hasn't yet really been answered.)