# Trying to work out why Python is recursively creating dirs

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a directory containing many subdirectories. Here is my code:

```
def organiseData():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_name):
        for dirName in sorted(dirs):
            print(root + '/' + dirName)
            if not os.path.exists(root + '/' + dirName + '/xml'):
                os.mkdir(root + '/' + dirName + '/xml')
```

It creates the directory inside each subdirectory okay, but then in the first subdirectory in the list it keeps making xml dirs inside xml dirs recursively until:

```
Sequence_3525/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml/xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "organiseData.py", line 74, in <module>
organiseData()
File "organiseData.py", line 8, in organiseData
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_name):

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Answer (score 3):

The `dirs` value yielded from `os.walk` represents the list of directories that are traversed in the following iterations (see [this for an example of why that's useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859840/excluding-directories-in-os-walk)).

Each time you create a new xml folder in a directory from `dirs`, `os.walk` later enters your new directory and creates more xml folders since the ones you created are empty.

Try making the check at the `root` level instead. For example:

```
def organize_data(directory_name):
    for root, subdirs, filenames in os.walk(directory_name):
        for sub in sorted(subdirs):
            print(os.path.join(root, sub))
        xml_dir = os.path.join(root, 'xml')
        if not os.path.exists(xml_dir):
            os.mkdir(xml_dir)
```

Another way to get around this is to prune `dirs` by removing all directories that you've already created xml folders in. Like this:

```
def organize_data(directory_name):
    for root, dirs, filenamess in os.walk(directory_name):
        for dir_name in sorted(dirs):
            print(os.path.join(root, dir_name))
            xml_dir = os.path.join(root, dir_name, 'xml')
            if not os.path.exists(xml_dir):
                os.mkdir(xml_dir)
                dirs.remove(dir_name) # Prevents infinite loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Directories are traversed from top down by default.  Since you create directories in subdirectories, you keep finding more directories.  Search bottom-up instead with:

```
os.walk(...,topdown=False)
```

Since the search will start in the deepest directories, adding a deeper `xml` directory won't affect the iteration.

Quote from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

> If optional argument topdown is True or not specified, the triple for
>   a directory is generated before the triples for any of its
>   subdirectories (directories are generated top-down). If topdown is
>   False, the triple for a directory is generated after the triples for
>   all of its subdirectories (directories are generated bottom-up). No
>   matter the value of topdown, the list of subdirectories is retrieved
>   before the tuples for the directory and its subdirectories are
>   generated.
>
> When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place
>   (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse
>   into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be
>   used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even
>   to inform walk() about directories the caller creates or renames
>   before it resumes walk() again. Modifying dirnames when topdown is
>   False has no effect on the behavior of the walk, because in bottom-up
>   mode the directories in dirnames are generated before dirpath itself
>   is generated.

Also FYI, `os.path.join()` is a cleaner way to join directories together, e.g. `os.path.join(root,dirname,'xml')`.