# Exclude specific folders and subfolders in os.walk

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, lambda

List all the files having ext .txt in the current directory .

```
L = [txt for f in os.walk('.') 
            for txt in glob(os.path.join(file[0], '*.txt'))]
```

I want to avoid files from **one specific directory and its subdirectories** . Lets say I do not want to dig into `folder3` and its available subdirectories to get the `.txt` files. I tried below

```
d = list(filter(lambda x : x != 'folder3', next(os.walk('.'))[1]))
```

but further steps not able to figure it out.How to include both to work together?

**EDIT**:

I tried referring the link provided as already answered query but I am unable to get desired output with below and surprisingly getting empty list as output for `a`

```
a=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
  dirs[:] = list(filter(lambda x : x != 'folder3', dirs)) 
  for txt in glob(os.path.join(file[0], '*.txt')): 
      a.append(txt)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excluding directories in os.walk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859840/excluding-directories-in-os-walk)

Comment: Its kind of duplicate but seems doesnot serves my purpose as per my requirement and the above code but let me try ..

Comment: @Isma The link referred by you is not helping me with my code .Need Help.

Comment: `a=[] 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):    
    dirs[:] = list(filter(lambda x : x != 'folder3', dirs))
    for pdf in glob(os.path.join(file[0], '*.txt')):
        a.append(txt)`
`a` is giving empty list as output, however there are other folders available. @Isma

Comment: @Isma I think `for pdf in glob(os.path.join(file[0], '*.txt')` needs to be fixed so that it should avoid  digging `folder3`

Comment: @Isma Can you help me with drafting it .. I am not sure how to mold my existing above code in the question as per the provided link .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following solution seems to be working, any directory specified in the exclude set will be ignored, any extension in the extensions set will be included.

```
import os

exclude = set(['folder3'])
extensions = set(['.txt', '.dat'])
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('c:/temp/folder', topdown=True):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
    files = [file for file in files if os.path.splitext(file)[1] in extensions]
    for fname in files:
        print(fname)
```

This code uses the option `topdown=True` to modify the list of dir names in place as specified in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

> When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place
>   (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse
>   into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be
>   used to prune the search

Comment: What is splittext? Can it be done for other filetype?

Comment: That's to get the extension. Check the last edit, you can now specify multiple extensions.

Comment: The documentation for [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) explicitly says that if `topdown=True` (which is the default) then modifying the `dirs` directory achieve what the OP wants. You could probably add a quote to the docs to clarify that this is not an accident...

Comment: Thanks for the elobrate answer. I found this also working from one of the recent stack post 
`for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
   if "folder3" not in root:
       for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                print (os.path.join(root, file))` . 
The answer you provided is very helpful if we have to ignore multiple directories.

Comment: Yes, the intention is that - if my code is in `Desktop` and  inside it I have multiple folders and their respective subfolders. but let me give that a try

Comment: @Isma Its traversing inside folders and subfolders inside the current directory . It can be used with function so that file ext can be passed as per our need. I found it easy to use without much code, please test from your end as well.Your time and answer is much appreciated also, I am marking it as a solution.

Comment: For the record, this solution only works for direct child directories - it doesn't work if the path you want to exclude is e.g. `folder4/folder41`, but want to include the rest of `folder4`. This ofc wasn't required by the original asker.

Comment: For my end, one could replace the sixth line with `dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if os.path.join(root, d) not in exclude]` and also `exclude` should contain absolute paths instead of relative ones.