# Ignore files from specific directory using glob or by os.walk()

Tags: python

I want to exclude the directory 'dir3_txt' so that I can only capture the `files('.txt')` from other directory . I tried to exclude directory like below but not able to figure it out how to get all the files having .txt as ext other that having it in `dir3_txt` using below:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
   print (root)
   dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d.startswith('dir3')]
   for file in files:
        print (os.path.join(root, file))
```

I am thinking of glob (got below from stack itself) but not sure how to tweak glob to use it.

```
for file in os.walk('.'):
   for txt in glob(os.path.join(files[0], '*.txt')):
       print(txt)
```

I went through [Excluding directories in os.walk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859840/excluding-directories-in-os-walk) but the solution provided is not helping me, also it only tells about skipping directory that also is not helpful as I need to get files from other directories , better if we can do it with glob only?

Comment: what your dir tree looks like?

Comment: @georgexsh In current working directory , lets say `/home/users/steve/Desktop` , I have multiple separate folders like `dir1 , dir2, dir3_txt, dir4`  and inside `dir3_txt` there can be subfolders having txt files as well. Script is placed  in  `/home/users/steve/Desktop`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would just to do a string comparison against the directory-paths and files returned by `os.walk`:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
   if "/dir3_txt/" not in root:
       for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                print (os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: But how to include `glob` here to get all the files `.txt` from other directories and its subdirectories.  I tried to put  `for txt in glob(os.path.join(files[0], '*.txt')):` under the second for loop but its not working to list .txt

Comment: do a string comparison against the file (see my edit)

Comment: you could use `fnmatch` for filename matching.

Answer (score 1):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
   print (root)
   dirs[:]= [d for d in dirs if d[:4]!='dir3']
   for file in files:
      if file[-4:]=='.txt':
        print (os.path.join(root, file))
```

I dont have any system with me now to test this , so if any problems please comment.

Edit:

Now it only detects '.txt' files.