# How do I specify a file that doesn't exist in a path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I have used this to find a file in a given path:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\derpderp\\"
name = "derp.xlsx"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if name in files:
        print(name)
```

But how do one go about doing the inverse? So that if the file not exist: specify that file.

If I write:

```
if name not in files:
    print(name)
```

It will iterate the file name that not exist for every folder/file etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excluding directories in os.walk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859840/excluding-directories-in-os-walk)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. It feels like an XY problem (is `os.walk` actually the tool you should use?). Please explain in words what you are trying to achieve, what is your input and what output you expect

Comment: I have an excel file with a list of filenames, I want to compare those filenames to a directory and subdirs. If a file from the list does not exist in any of the dirs, i want to print that filename.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pathlib's [`resolve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) function and try/except for a `FileNotFound` error.

```py
import pathlib

path = "C:\\Users\\derpderp\\"
name = "derp.xlsx"

try:
    file = pathlib.Path(path+name)
    file.resolve(strict=True)
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(name)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: or just `os.path.exists`

Comment: Does this not generate exactly the same problem i had before? If i iterate this through a dir with subdirs, it will print the name of the missing file for every dir.

Answer (score 0):

Although using the `pathlib` module as shown in @Ben Corcoran answer would probably the best (and fastest) way to do it, here's an alternative that uses the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
import os

def any_exists(filename, path):
    def gen_files(path):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            if filename in files:
                return filename
        return ()

    return any(gen_files(path))


path = "C:\\Users\\martineau"
name = "derp.xlsx"

if not any_exists(name, path):
    print(f'No file named {name} exists.')
else:
    print(f'A file named {name} exists.')
```