# Traverse root "/" without leaving filesystem

Tags: python, macos

`os.walk` in python when used on `/` directory descends into `/Volumes` and starts traversing external drives. How can I traverse all directories without leaving current filesystem?

Comment: You could write a custom recursive traversal using ```os.listdir()```

Comment: How do I know I'm still on the same filesystem?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859840/excluding-directories-in-os-walk

Comment: you can maybe make use of the `pathlib` module