# "snipping" a subdirectory tree from os.walk()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a function that will recursively check all directories in a drive, that part works fine. However, I want to ignore everything in a certain directory, in this case if the directory has `"win"` or `"$win"` in it.

**Code:**

```
def without_system_files(drive:str, lookup_name:str):
    print(f"Searching... {drive.title()}:\\", end="\r")

    # gets all directories
    for cur_dir, _, _ in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        # skips to the next directory if it's a windows file
        if "win" in path.lower() or "$win" in path.lower()  # ---HERE---
            continue
        # gets all files
        files = os.listdir(cur_dir)
        # for every file in the dir
        for file in files:
            # make a proper path, if it's the root folder, don't add another \
            if len(cur_dir) != 3:
                path = cur_dir + "\\" + file
            else:
                path = cur_dir + file
            # if the file has the lookup_name (we use file opposed to path because path would return positive if the folder fits the check for lookup_name)
            if lookup_name in file:
                # if path is a file
                if os.path.isfile(path):
                    #found_files = found_files + ("\nFound file at: " + path)
                    print("Found file at: " + path)
```

The `---HERE---` comment indicates my current solution for this, but it checks every subdir in the dir, I wast it to ignore the entire "tree" of directories if this returns true

**Things of note:**
This is written in `python 3.11`
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859840/excluding-directories-in-os-walk) does not meet my requirements, assuming I understand the answers in that thread

Comment: `os.walk()` gives you lists of the subdirectories and files in the current directory being walked - but you're simply throwing these away.  Calling `os.listdir()` is pointless, you had the list of files already.  And you are allowed to remove elements from the subdirectories list, to prevent walking into them.

Comment: @jasonharper I didn't realize `os.walk()` returned files and dirs aswell, thank you!