# Recursive file renaming in python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to write some code to recursively renaming files in python. I've got a root folder which has another folder inside it, and yet another folder inside that folder. Each of this folders has a file named "Name.txt" and I would like to change them to "Test.txt", in order to understand how os.walk() and os.rename() work. I've written this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os


def renamefiles(path):

    rootstructure=os.walk(path,topdown=False)
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(rootstructure):

        for filenames in files:

        fullfilename=os.path.abspath(filenames)

        os.rename(fullfilename,"Test.txt")



renamefiles(".")
```

However, I get this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 278, in walk
names = listdir(top)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, generator found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not using `os.walk` properly, see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989005/do-i-understand-os-walk-right)

Comment: You shouldn't be posting answers with your updated code. Edit the original question with your updates and delete the "answers", as they don't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

`os.rename` can be destructive. Use it carefully.

You had `rootstructure` initialised to os.walk for somereason. You need to initialize it to the path of the current directory.

```
import os

def renamefiles(path):
    rootstructure=os.path.abspath(path)

    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(rootstructure):
        for filenames in files:
            fullfilename=os.path.abspath(filenames)
            print(fullfilename)
            # Use this carefuly, it can wipe off your entire system
            # if not used carefully
            os.rename(fullfilename,"Test.txt")

renamefiles(".")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a string representing a path to `os.walk`.  Currently, you are passing `rootstructure`, which is a generator object.

```
def renamefiles(path):
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for filenames in files:
            fullfilename=os.path.abspath(filenames)

            # YOU PROBABLY WANT TO CHECK THE FILENAME BEFORE RENAMING!
            # WHAT IF THE FILE IS NOT Name.txt !
            os.rename(fullfilename,"Test.txt")

renamefiles(".")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

The suggested changes are as follows:

- Use `os.getcwd()` instead of `"."` since it doesn't seem to be resolved the way you want. This will be illustrated in the diagnostics function.
- Use **relative path renaming** by `os.chdir(root)`. Of course using *correct* absolute paths also works, but IMHO relative paths are just more elegant.
- Pass an unambiguous string into `os.walk()` as others have mentioned.

Also note that `topdown=False` in `os.walk()` doesn't matter. Since you are not renaming directories, the directory structure will be invariant during `os.walk()`.

## Code Sample

Original file structure:

```
bill@Bill-deb:/mnt/ramdisk/test$ tree .
.
├── outer
│   ├── inner
│   │   └── innermost.txt
│   └── inner.txt
├── outer.txt
└── rename.py
```

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

def renamefiles(path):

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
        for f in files:
            # chdir before renaming
            os.chdir(root)  
            if f != "rename.py":  # avoid renaming this file
                os.rename(f, "renamed.txt")  # relative path, more elegant


renamefiles(os.getcwd())  # pass an unambiguous string
```

Resulted file structure:

```
bill@Bill-deb:/mnt/ramdisk/test$ tree .
.
├── outer
│   ├── inner
│   │   └── renamed.txt
│   └── renamed.txt
├── renamed.txt
└── rename.py
```

Tested under debian 8.6 64-bit, python 2.7.12 (Anaconda 4.1.1).

## For Diagnostics

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

def renamefiles_check(path):

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):

        for f in files:
            print "========="
            print "os.getcwd() = {}".format(os.getcwd())
            print "root = {}".format(root)
            print "f = {}".format(f)
            print "os.path.abspath(f) = {}".format(os.path.abspath(f))
            print "os.path.join(root, f) = {}".format(os.path.join(root, f))

# renamefiles_check(".")
# renamefiles_check(os.getcwd())
```

The first few lines of `renamefiles_check(".")` are shown here:

```
os.getcwd() = /mnt/ramdisk/test
root = ./outer/inner
f = innermost.txt
os.path.abspath(f) = /mnt/ramdisk/test/innermost.txt
os.path.join(root, f) = ./outer/inner/innermost.txt
```

You can verify that:

- The behavior `os.path.abspath(f)` is not *desired* (not to say it's wrong). It always binds to the parameter `path` that was passed into `os.walk()` instead of the path containing file `f`.
- When `"."` is passed as `path`, the dot in `os.path.join(root, f)` is still not fully resolved.

The sample code avoids these ambiguities.