# os.walk is very slow for recursively accessing folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, subdirectory, os.walk, scandir

My data-set have more than 1000 folders and i am using `os.walk` for recursively accessing each image inside every folder. `os.walk` went well for few folders but loading 1000 more folders its very slow. I need alternate solution or if anything that can handle this issue.
You can see the code something similar:

```
def run(dirname, img):
    data = img.load()
    width, height = img.size
    output_img = Image.new("RGB", (100, 100))
    Zero=np.zeros(shape=(100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)

    for (x, y) in labels:
        component = uf.find(labels[(x, y)])
        labels[(x, y)] = component
        path = 'D:/Python36/Fold/'
        if labels[(x, y)] == 0:
            Zero[y][x] = 255
            Zeroth = Image.fromarray(Zero)
            Zeroth.save(os.path.join(dirname, 'Zero.png'), 'png')


def main():
    path = "D:/Python36/Fold/"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file_ in files:
            img = Image.open(os.path.join(root, file_))
            img = img.point(lambda p: p > 190 and 255)
            img = img.convert('1')
            (labels, output_img) = run(root, img)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried and failed?

Comment: What is your question? You want to search an alternate solution that would be more effective? Not clear

Comment: What does "very slow" mean?

Comment: You may do it in a wrong way. You should show your code.

Comment: `os.walk` is probably much faster than "accessing each image" and thus not the real culprit.

Comment: How do you know `os.walk` is the slow part? Remove image manipulation parts and see how much it takes to list all the files.

Comment: my code stucks at folder 10 and 100 and generates completely different out put when i removed those 2 folders it worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debug your code and execute file sequentially you can use `sorted(os.walk(path))` and check at which file your code slows down.
check this it might 
[help how os.walk works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989005/do-i-understand-os-walk-right)

Answer (score 2):

You question is not clear but Python has `os.scandir` that don't call stat on each file and is much faster. [Related doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir).

PyPI package for old Python versions (<3.5) https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scandir.

Comment: @MunSays `os.scandir` can do roughly the same thing as `os.walk` you'll have to read the docs (which Arman has provided) to see how it works.