# Python: Find all files in a directory recursively?

Tags: python, search, find

I would like to find all the files in a directory and all the subdirectories recursively, basically what I want is the equivalent of this sell command in Python:

```
find <dirname> -type f
```

I have read the solution using os.walk(), glob() but they all work on a specific path, so I need to write a program to recursively call these methods, is there any other straightforward solution for that?

Comment: `os.walk()` already does exactly this, **recursively** listing files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989005/do-i-understand-os-walk-right 
Refer to this for details.