# How does the iteration of os.walk work in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

According to the Python 3 [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) `os.walk` returns a 3-tuple. However, this does not work:

```
root, dirs, files = os.walk('path')
```

Neither does this:

```
(root, dirs, files) = os.walk('path')
```

It always yields:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

All the examples for `os.walk` I found embed `os.walk` in a for loop:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path'):
```

Why? What exactly will be iterated here? `root` is a string, `dirs` and `files` are lists. However, most examples iterate again over `dirs` and `files`:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path'):
    for name in files:
        print(name)
    for name in dirs:
        print(name)
```

The inner for loops make sense to me, but I don't get what the outer for loop is for.

And why does the assignment to the 3-tuple work when `os.walk` is embedded in a for loop, but not without one?

Comment: I seems to yield root, dirs and files. So if you are in A, it will yield /A, dirsinsideA and filesinsideA. Next iteration will yield the first subdirectory. It is my guess.

Comment: Just because you can do `for x,y,z in some_iterable` does **not mean** you can do `x,y,z = some_iterable`. In fact, that is almost never the case, it only will ever work if `some_iterable` contains exactly three objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I understand os.walk right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989005/do-i-understand-os-walk-right)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.walk` doesn't **return a** 3-tuple, it **yields multiple** 3-tuples. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

> For each directory in the tree rooted at directory *top* (including *top* itself), it yields a 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`.

For how yielding works, see [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/4518341) (You can ignore the example code given by OP.) Technically `os.walk` returns a generator that yields the 3-tuples.

The outer `for` loop iterates over the 3-tuples. You're probably confused by the unpacking that happens in the same step. So to be clear,

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(top):
```

is effectively the same as

```
for branch in os.walk(top):
    dirpath, dirnames, filenames = branch
```

Comment: Could you please expand on that? What's the difference between returning and yielding?

Comment: Yielding is for iterators. Instead of returning a full length array, it will return only the needed for the iteration, thus saving memory space.

Comment: @user1785730 See [What does the “yield” keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/4518341) (You can ignore the example code OP gives.)

Comment: Thanks, that was an interesting read and answers most of my questions. The one remaining is: What are the values the outer for loop iterates over?

Comment: @user1785730 I added that to my answer

Answer (score 2):

os.walk returns an [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) not a tuple!
If you want to look up values from your generator output convert it to a list:

```
test = list(os.walk("."))
```