# Python: Too many values to unpack (what does the os.walk function return)

Tags: python-3.x

Basically my question boils down to "What does `os.walk` actually return?"

I'm carrying out a simple experiment:

```
list(os.walk('test_dir'))[0]
```

yields the following result:

```
('test_dir', [], ['somefile1', 'somefile2'])
```

So it does seem that the os.walk function in this case returns a generator of a tuple. I can also write something like this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('test_dir'):
    pass
```

but if I, say, do the following:

```
for root, dirs, files in (item for item in list(os.walk('test_dir'))[0]):
    pass
```

I will get the above-mentioned error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)"

I don't understand why.

Comment: In the second example you are iterating over the three elements in `list(os.walk('test_dir')[0]` (i.e. the path, directory names, and file names of the first node in the dir tree)  one by one, so in the first iteration, the path name will be unpacked to `root`, `dirs`, and `files`, in the second iteration the list of directory names and in the third iteration the list of file names.

Comment: Related: [Do I understand os.walk right?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10989005/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea Corrected the typo. It is related but it by no means answers the question.

Comment: @Heike So basically it tries unpacking `test_dir` to root, dirs, files...

Comment: BTW, the more efficient way of getting the first element of a generator is `next(gen)`, instead of `list(gen)[0]`, since it just gets the next element instead of making a list of all the elements then selecting the first one.

Comment: Also BTW, `(item for item in iterable)` is redundant. Just use `iterable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know that `list(os.walk(...))[0] == ('test_dir', [], ['somefile1', 'somefile2'])`, which is a tuple.

This code:

```
for a, b, c in thing:
    ...
```

...is the same as this:

```
for something in thing:
    a, b, c = something
    ...
```

This part: `a, b, c = something` is called "iterable unpacking".

Note that the loop will attempt to iterate over each element of `thing`. In your case, it'll try to iterate over each of the three elements of your tuple, and on the first iteration `something == 'test_dir'`, which is an iterable that contains 8 elements.

However, `a, b, c = something` expects it to have exactly three elements. So, you get an error saying that there were too many values to unpack (expected 3 but got 8).

Comment: And how come it still works for the `for a, b, c in os.walk` case?

Comment: @igor, `os.walk` returns a list of tuples, each of which contains three elements, so `something` would be that tuple, which is exactly what `a, b, c = something` expects