# os.walk error , can't fill list with file names

Tags: python, arrays, iteration, google-colaboratory, stopiteration

I'm learning "Google colab" and got some problem with data reading. I've written a python script for filling folders names into arrays, but it doesn't fill at even one.

```py
TEST_PATH = "/content/gdrive/'My Drive'/test/"
test_ids= []
try:
    test_ids = next(os.walk(TEST_PATH))[1]
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

list "test_ids" still empty, but there are some folders with files in TEST_PATH:
[here you can check it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP92R.png)

Comment: Ive seen os.walk used like this:  `for root,dirs,files in os.walk(....): # do smth` maybe try that?

Comment: @PatrickArtner No, it didn't help. Still empty(

Comment: `os.path.isdir( TEST_PATH )` ?

Comment: What is empty? dirs? files?

Comment: dirs. But I've already solved problem, thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your path like this: `TEST_PATH = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/test/"`

And to list files, I think it should be this: `next(os.walk(TEST_PATH))[2]`.

`next(os.walk(TEST_PATH))[1]` will list the folders.

You can see more details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10989155/11524628

Comment: i need to list the folders, sorry for misleading you

Comment: Could you change the path like this `TEST_PATH = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/test/"`?

Comment: wow, it worked, my bad, thank you