# How rm .xml in differents folders

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to do a python3 script and i have to delete all .xml in  a folder.
It's a giant folder with any folders in this folders (etc..).

(in dossier1, i have 2 folders and 2 .xml files, in there 2 folders, i have 2 folders and 2 .xml files etc)

Is it possible to say: "in this folder, search all the .xml and delete them" ?

i tried this:

```
filelist=os.listdir(path)
    for fichier in filelist[:]: # filelist[:] makes a copy of filelist.
        if not(fichier.endswith(".xml")):
            filelist.remove(fichier)
```

but python dont't go in differents folders.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10989155/8243797) answer gives good info about it.
You can do something like this

```
for path, directories, files in os.walk('./'): # change './' to directory path
      for file in files: 
           fname = os.path.join(path, file) 
           if fname.endswith('.xml'): # If file ends with .xml
               print(fname) 
               os.remove(os.path.abspath(fname))# Use absolute path to remove file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pathlib.Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob):

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> list(pathlib.Path('.').glob("**/*.xml"))
[PosixPath('b.xml'), PosixPath('a.xml'), PosixPath('test/y.xml'), PosixPath('test/x.xml')]
>>> _[0].unlink() # delete some file
>>> for file in pathlib.Path('.').glob("**/*.xml"):
...   print(file)
...   file.unlink() # delete everything
... 
a.xml
test/y.xml
test/x.xml
```