# TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'tuple'

Tags: python, file, zip, pathlib

I want to process all the files in my `path`.
If its a zip file, I want to extract its content as `img`.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
import os
import sys
import pathlib

path = "./CODEX/input/"

for filename in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'r') as f:
        # Antibody information
        ab = pd.read_excel("HUBMAP B004 codex antibodies metadata.xlsx")
        # TODO: Rename antibody_name column so that it matches channelNames.txt
        
        # CODEX images
        if filename.endswith(".zip"):
            img = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.abspath(filename)).extractall(path)
            print(img)
```

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_18751/2066110210.py in <module>
>       1 for filename in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
> ----> 2     with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'r') as f:
>       3         # Antibody information
>       4         ab = pd.read_excel("HUBMAP B004 codex antibodies metadata.xlsx")
>       5         # TODO: Rename antibody_name column so that it matches channelNames.txt
> 
> /usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py in join(a, *p)
>      88                 path += sep + b
>      89     except (TypeError, AttributeError, BytesWarning):
> ---> 90         genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
>      91         raise
>      92     return path
> 
> /usr/lib/python3.8/genericpath.py in _check_arg_types(funcname, *args)
>     150             hasbytes = True
>     151         else:
> --> 152             raise TypeError(f'{funcname}() argument must be str, bytes, or '
>     153                             f'os.PathLike object, not {s.__class__.__name__!r}') from None
>     154     if hasstr and hasbytes:
> 
> TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object,
> not 'tuple'
```

Comment: I guess `os.walk` returns a `tuple` object, but you might be expecting a `str`

Comment: This link might help: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I understand os.walk right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989005/do-i-understand-os-walk-right)

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.listdir() instead os.walk()

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    pass
```