# Incorrect Numbering of WebP Files in Directory Traverse Script

Tags: python, directory, directory-structure, webp, os.walk

I wanted to create a code that would go through my directory and for folders in a specific position of the path, it would insert in a .txt, it creates in each different child folder, the number that those child folder's webp files are associated with in relation to the parent folder, alphabetically. Starting from 0 for each different parent folder (consider that there will be parent folders that are called in the same way, so to indentify each different parent folder I associated not just the name but the root before aswell, so they're truly unique).

However the code is NOT working as expected as it will number each like this:

- Created "Image Position.txt" in "C:\users\utente\desktop\randomizza colori\Boxy Hoodie\Both\Back\0009 INSECURITY\14 white" with contents: 1,2
- Created "Image Position.txt" in "C:\users\utente\desktop\randomizza
  colori\Boxy Hoodie\Both\Back\0009 INSECURITY\15 grey" with contents:
  3,4
- Created "Image Position.txt" in "C:\users\utente\desktop\randomizza
  colori\Boxy Hoodie\Both\Back\0009 INSECURITY\22 red" with contents:
  5,6
- Created "Image Position.txt" in "C:\users\utente\desktop\randomizza
  colori\Boxy Hoodie\Both\Back\0009 INSECURITY\35 black" with contents:
  7,8
- Created "Image Position.txt" in "C:\users\utente\desktop\randomizza
  colori\Boxy Hoodie\Both\Back\0009 INSECURITY\9 blue" with contents:
  9,10"

While it should've been:

- Created "Image Position.txt" in "C:\users\utente\desktop\randomizza
  colori\Boxy Hoodie\Both\Back\0009 INSECURITY\9 blue" with contents:
  1,2"
- Created "Image Position.txt" in "C:\users\utente\desktop\randomizza
  colori\Boxy Hoodie\Both\Back\0009 INSECURITY\14 white" with contents:
  3,4
- Created "Image Position.txt" in "C:\users\utente\desktop\randomizza
  colori\Boxy Hoodie\Both\Back\0009 INSECURITY\15 grey" with contents:
  5,6
- Created "Image Position.txt" in "C:\users\utente\desktop\randomizza
  colori\Boxy Hoodie\Both\Back\0009 INSECURITY\22 red" with contents:
  7,8
- Created "Image Position.txt" in "C:\users\utente\desktop\randomizza
  colori\Boxy Hoodie\Both\Back\0009 INSECURITY\35 black" with contents:
  9,10

Here is the code:

```
import os
import re

# Define the base directory
fold_A = r'C:\users\utente\desktop\randomizza colori'

# This dictionary will hold the count of webp files per design
design_webp_count = {}

# Traverse the directory structure
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fold_A):
    # Check if there are any webp files in the current directory
    webp_files = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.webp')]
    if webp_files:
        # Extract the design name from the path (assuming it's the fourth folder in the path)
        path_parts = root.split(os.sep)
        if len(path_parts) > 4:
            design_name = path_parts[-2]
            root_before_design = os.sep.join(path_parts[:-2])  # Updated line to get all levels above {design}
            
            if (design_name, root_before_design) not in design_webp_count:
                design_webp_count[(design_name, root_before_design)] = 0
            # Count the webp files in this design folder
            design_webp_count[(design_name, root_before_design)] += len(webp_files)
            # Create the "Image Position.txt" file
            position_file_path = os.path.join(root, "Image Position.txt")
            with open(position_file_path, 'w') as position_file:
                # Write the comma-separated positions to the file
                positions = [str(design_webp_count[(design_name, root_before_design)] - len(webp_files) + i + 1) for i in range(len(webp_files))]
                position_file.write(','.join(positions))
                # Print the directory and the contents of the "Image Position.txt" file
                print(f'Created "Image Position.txt" in {root} with contents: {",".join(positions)}')

# Print "FINITO" once finished
print("FINITO")
```

Comment: there is alot going on here. Some variables defined but not used eg `sorted_webp_files`. Note that your issue lies with how the data is arranged.

Comment: Hi Onyambu, thank you so much with the response.

I cannot manage to figure out how to get this working, would you be able to give a hand? I'm completely aware that you're time is priceless, so I appreciate just you having taken the time to respond in the case you don't want to help out. Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure how you compute the contents, but the order into which the contents are written matters. Does the content depend on directory number? Note that the order of directories is string sorted at best. So you need to ensure that contents are associated with each folder somehow.

Comment: The contents of each .txt file depend on the webp position of each webp in each "color_name" inside each different "design_name" which must be uniquely indentified also with the root as I have folders that have that same name but different root.

For example: if i have a folder A that contains other 3 folder called A1 A2 A3, and each of these contain 2 webp. I want the code to write inside A1 (the first folder inside A in alphabetical order) "1,2", and inside A2 "3,4" and inside A3 "5,6". Understood?

However now it writes numbers that i don't understand as you can see from output i gave

Comment: I tried debugging seeing how "os.walks" goes through and in fact the order it goes through doesn't follow the alphabetical order of the name of each folder. I have no idea how to solve this as trying to sort os.walk to walk in alphabetical order it still will have sort of allucinations that will f up the order

Comment: In short the contents are not associated with the files but rather just with the order of the files.in that case you will have to sort the directories. Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670029/can-i-force-os-walk-to-visit-directories-in-alphabetical-order

Comment: os.walk result is undefined. You will have to sort the directories in place. Also I hope you can maintain the same number of digits for string sorting

Comment: Hey thank you for the response once again. I tried this import os

fold_A = r'C:\users\utente\desktop\randomizza colori'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fold_A):
    dirs.sort()  # Sort directories alphabetically
    for dir_name in dirs:
        print("Current Directory:", os.path.join(root, dir_name))

However the result is not consistent as it will print this "..\0085\16 blue" "\29 white" "\3 grey" "\31 black" "50 red" It seams like for single digits it messes up

Comment: Chatgpt solved it with this def numeric_sort(value):
    # Extract numerical part of the directory name
    try:
        return int(value.split()[0])  # Assuming the numerical part comes before the space
    except ValueError:
        return value

# Traverse the directory structure
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fold_A):
    dirs.sort(key=numeric_sort)  # Sort directories alphabetically with numerical consideration
    # Check if there are any webp files in the current directory

Comment: You forgot to pass in a key on how you want it sorted

Comment: Please do not use the key from chatgpt. instead use `from natsort import natsort_key` then pass `dirs.sort(key = natsort_key)` if you do not have `natsort` you can install it using `pip install natsort`. natsort is for natural sorting

Comment: Hope this solves your issue. Any further problem? sorry for taking long to respond. its 5am. been awake the whole night

Comment: Not at all thank youso much Onya